# Regex pattern for URL in casperjs

Tags: regex, testing, pattern-matching, automated-tests, casperjs

In casperJS I'm writing a test case to open a URL in popup.

URL looks like this

> https://api{domain_name}/facilities/{facility_id}/assessments/{assessment_id}/print_preview

I want to get regex for the above URL to be used with

```
withPopup(Mixed popupInfo, Function then)
```

I have tried these regex patterns

- `/assessment/`
- `/assessment$/`
- `/print_preview/`
- `/$print_preview$/`

Please help me in creating the right regex for above mentioned URL.

Comment: it is not clear, what part of the url you want to select... please clarify, or use this to play around with your regex: https://regex101.com/r/uV5wH5/1

Comment: Basic format / grammar corrections.

Comment: I think what hexerei software wants to say is that you define what kind of characters are expected for `{facility_id}` and `{assessment_id}`. Are those digits or alphanumerics? Do those included other characters?

Comment: {facility_id} and {assessment_id} are integers always.
I just want a regex that can be used to open above mentioned url in popup.
@hexereisoftware I want to select this full URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used /assessments/ and it worked :-)